# Django - linking multiple ChoiceField's

Tags: python, django, forms, choicefield

I need to have user inputing his address by first select country, then city, then district, and then sub-district.  How do I best implement this functionality in django Form?  The models are similar to this:

```
Class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

Class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

Class District(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)

Class Subdistrict(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filtering results based on the value of other fields in the form](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form) from [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html)

Comment: Can u also comment on the use of django-smart-selects ?  According to the example in the document, the model District in  my example needs to have foreign keys not only of City but also of Country which is a different design from what I have,  meaning I have to rebuild the models and database tables to add additional foreign keys